# Make Blacklist JWT tokens for spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt, blacklist

Hello everyone I am for weeks on this problem make a blacklist of chips JWT with spring boot here is what I did when the user tries to disconnect his store his key token in the given database of mongoDB and it works

```
@PutMapping(value = "/destroy", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public JwtBlacklist logout(@RequestBody Map<String,String> json, HttpSession httpSession) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String token = json.get("token");

    JwtBlacklist jwtBlacklist = new JwtBlacklist();
    jwtBlacklist.setToken(token);
    jwtBlacklistRepository.save(jwtBlacklist);

    return jwtBlacklistRepository.save(jwtBlacklist);
}
```

It stores the key in the given database perfectly without any worries
here are the pictures
https://ibb.co/dcX0Vnh "tokenStore"

Now the biggest problem this when I try to blacklist the tokens that the user has to use during its connection and when it disconnects this token is no longer valid here the code I JWTFilter.java

```
public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    public String jwtsecret;
    @Autowired
    public JwtBlacklistRepository jwtBlacklistRepository;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req,
                         final ServletResponse res,
                         final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");

        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {

            if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                throw new ServletException("Missing or invalid Authorization header");
            }

            final String token = authHeader.substring(7);
            JwtBlacklist blacklist = this.jwtBlacklistRepository.findByTokenEquals(token);

                    if(blacklist == null) {
                        final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("topsecretjwtpass".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                        request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
                    } else {
                        throw new ServletException("Invalid token." + "");

                    }

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

    }
}
```

Now when i try to make a query with the blacklist tokens or without the black list tokens i have this error

> {"timestamp":"2019-08-27T11:54:52.063+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal
>   Server Error","message":"No message
>   available","trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat
>   com.monarque.bank.monarque.config.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:47)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:151)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\n\tat
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\n\tat
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)\n","path":"/v1/users/fa26eea5-7dce-4d79-a7f7-1f848cc58966"}

---

Here is the model

```
public class JwtBlacklist {
    @Id
    private String _id;
    @Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
    private String token;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JwtBlacklist{" +
                "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
                ", token='" + token + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

---

This is the repository of the JwtBlacklist

```
import com.monarque.bank.monarque.dao.models.JwtBlacklist;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;


public interface JwtBlacklistRepository extends MongoRepository<JwtBlacklist,String> {


JwtBlacklist findByTokenEquals(String token);

}
```

Comment: Hi, instead of using @Autowired inside the JWTFilter, you should receive this as constructor and pass this inside where you are creating the JWTFilter instance. 
Probably in a SecurityConfig or something. Another option is making JWTFilter a component then the autowired will work

Comment: you can make an example so that I can better understand

Comment: hi @taylor-marshall just added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise, the problem happens because your JWTFilter it is not managed by Spring so you can't just ask him to inject the beans and properties for you.

Luckily for you, there is an easy way to make things work!

Try and see if adding the following init method works for you:

```
public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
  @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
  public String jwtsecret;
  @Autowired
  public JwtBlacklistRepository jwtBlacklistRepository;

  //ask spring to inject the values based on current context
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req,
                       final ServletResponse res,
                       final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, 
  ServletException {

  ....
  }
}
```

This method, ask spring to do the injection for you.

Comment: I was stuck in deeper darkness of spring boot for weeks and you came to deliver me from this hell my black knight Thank you ❤️

Comment: @TaylorMarshall Glad I could help this much =)

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you are working within a **Filter Bean and Injecting a Bean in to a GenericFilter does not work**. 
One option I know to work around this problem is to **lazy load** your repository.

Just check in the **first line of doFilter()** if your repository is null, if so
get your servletContext and lazy load it. 
For example:

```
if (jwtBlacklistRepository == null) { //Lazy Load because filter
    ServletContext servletContext = req.getServletContext();
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    jwtBlacklistRepository = webApplicationContext.getBean(JwtBlacklistRepository.class);
}
```

Basically your are forcing to load that bean into your filter. (Please correct me if I am wrong with this statement).

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly I try your method it works for the blacklist jwt token his walk not his do not find the tokens that are blacklisted

Comment: please you can make a code to know which key is blacklisted or not in JWTFilter.java it will be super cool and nice of you

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to understand for me because English is not my mother tongue and also not yours I guess. Can you translate via https://www.deepl.com/translator please. It is hard to understand your first comment.

Comment: Is it correct that your token is not found in the JWT Blacklist Repository? How does your model and Repository look like? And why are you forcing a .substring(7) with the token.

Comment: Lol noticed you my English is actually bad I speak French so I tried your method and it works the problem is that you can't know the blacklisted tokens if you could make a complete code man it will be super cool on your part

Comment: Thanks also for your help ❤️